# Connection has been administratively destroyed - getting error in java application using weblogic server

Tags: java, connection, weblogic, connection-pooling, weblogic-10.x

We are using Weblogic version 10 for our java application and we are using Connection Pooling in our code.

We are getting few errors on the logs like:
Connection has been administratively disabled for multiple times. It happens randomly and not on a regular basis.

In some cases, we are getting an error like:
Connection has been administratively destroyed and whatever application process is running will be stopped.

We analyzed the code repository using PMD plugin to see if we have any connections that are not closed and didn't find anything that was related to the process that ran on the days which we faced the issue.

Also I have checked the weblogic admin console to see the number of max. connections it have created. It was around 20 only whereas the connection pool was having a min. and max. value of 100. So we got the error of connection has been administratively disabled even though the admin console showed the max no: of active connections that was made were 20.

It will be really helpful if anyone could suggest why we are receiving this error and how we can prevent this.
Also why am I seeing the count as 20 in admin console but still getting the error (my connection pool limit is 100)?

P.s: We are restarting our application daily.

Comment: Try this? http://robin4444.blogspot.com/2012/03/connection-has-been-administratively.html Are you getting other errors before `Connection has been administratively disabled` happens?

Comment: @casting: We are not getting any errors before this. This is the error we get:
14:31:46,394 [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '26' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR - SQLException Caught: Connection has been administratively disabled. Try later.

14:31:48,231 [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR  Exception getting Current Date of database: Connection has been administratively destroyed. Reconnect.

Comment: @casting: I missed to tell one point. 
I think as you told it might be a intermittent connection issue. I am new to this, could you please share your comments on the below:

Actually we have 2 application server (for the same application) that is connecting to the same Sybase DB. But all the time when we get this error it is in one box. We have never seen this error in the other box. Could you please tell me if we can have the connection issue always happen between only this application server and DB? Shouldn't at the same time we get the same error in the other app server?